# Synchronous AFNetworking calls

Tags: iphone, afnetworking, synchronous

I am currently using AFNetworking in one of my iPhone app. It's really a handy library to make asynchronous calls. However, I ran into situations in my application where I need to get the data from the server to move forward. So I figured this way of waiting for the response back.

```
    MyAFNetworkClient *httpClient = [MyAFNetworkClient sharedClient];

    NSURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:path parameters:nil];

__block int status = 0;

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notificationName" object:JSON];

} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON){
    @throw error.userInfo;
    status = 2;
    NSLog(@"Error... Status Code 2");

}];
[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
[httpClient.operationQueue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];

while (status == 0)
{
    // run runloop so that async dispatch can be handled on main thread AFTER the operation has
    // been marked as finished (even though the call backs haven't finished yet).
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                             beforeDate:[NSDate date]];
}
```

With this piece of code, I am able to wait for the response back from the server and able to proceed further. It really seemed to solve my problem, however, not sure if this is a good way to make the calls. If it is, is there a good design principle where I can keep the code common and use it across my application.

Thank you

Comment: I think the answers/comments here illustrate the opinion-based nature of this question.

Answer (score 12):

Never block the main (UI) thread. That is to say, never do networking synchronously.

The entire time your request loads, it will appear that your application has frozen—totally unresponsive to touch and system events until the request finishes.

At the very least, show a loading modal that doesn't dismiss until the request finishes. Even better, make it so a user can interact the app normally while the request is loading, if possible.

What you have here may technically work, but it's unacceptable for a real application.

Comment: @matt wrong! 1.: there may be reasons for blocking the main thread. I don't think you can rule it out for every single app in every situation. 2.: Doing requests synchronously doesn't mean to block the man thread. You may be in background already when you start a synchronous request.  For some reason the whole iOS-community unisono responds "DON'T" when somebody asks for synchronous network request.

Comment: @KaiHuppmann You are entirely mistaken. And in case you don't trust the unanimous opinion of the community, at least take Apple at their word: [(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1693/_index.html) [(2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/CommonPitfalls/CommonPitfalls.html)

Comment: What about when you need to download the property list, that is must for running the application? it is usable especially right after tapping 'Log me in' button. I have client settings data on the remote server and all the stuff has to respect these settings. When the pList not downloaded yet, the app cannot offer proper usage to the user.

Comment: @pedrouan As mentioned in the original answer, an app can still be interactive and display a loading indicator while the app is waiting for data to come in. Blocking the main thread of an app causes it to freeze, which makes for a really bad user experience.

Comment: Hi @mattt, it's not related to the original question but as far as you've stated, how can we execute a sequence of networking requests synchronously (of course not in main thread), one after another and the former's output is an input of the latter? Actually, we can achieve that use case by using async callback, but the code would be a nightmare. What do you suggest?

Comment: @mattt - both of the Apple links you posted discourage synchronous network requests on the main thread - they don't discuss synchronous networking on a background thread.  Any thoughts as to why we shouldn't be doing synchronous networking in the background?

Answer (score 0):

For all of them who are running into the same situation where you are making asynchronous calls and want to wait for the data to return back to the main thread to do other stuff, this might be of a little help

Scenario:

**User authentication**: User enters username, password and trying to log in.

**Solution**: Show them loading modal to tell them that is something is going on behind the scenes, once you get back the response, you can proceed to the main thread like below.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         // perform next steps....
        });

}
```

Thanks to @matt for the tip on what needs to be done in such cases.

Comment: Waiting for a fixed amount of time is not a viable option here - it's probably just as bad as doing synchronous networking.
You should always use the respective callback blocks AFNetworking provides.
To use them correctly you need to architect the rest of your application so that it's asynchronous-friendly. Delegation is a good idea to use then.

Comment: @MatthiasWenz is correct—this is not an acceptable solution.